# How to add include path in rosmake?

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For example:

I installed libvtk-5.8.

And I try to include vtkAppendPolyData.h not vtk-5.8/vtkAppendPolyData.h.

So I want to add an include path to rosmake or ubuntu system.

How to do that?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45220/how-to-add-include-path-in-rosmake?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If by 'add include path to rosmake' you mean you want to add a path to your compiler's include path, just add an `include_directories` statement to your `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
...
rosbuild_init()
...
include_directories(/path/to/vtk-5.8)
...
rosbuild_add_executable(your_app src/your_app.cpp)
...
target_link_libraries(your_app somelib otherlib)
...
```

Note though that in general, using absolute paths is not recommended. It seems there is a `FindVTK.cmake`, so `find_package(VTK ..) would be better.

---

Originally posted by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) with karma: 1416 on 2012-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2